# What happened to the Boeing Y3 aircraft?

Tags: boeing

What happened to the [Boeing Y3 aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Yellowstone_Project)? Did they ever produce a fully functional prototype? What is the likelihood that it will ever be produced, and when will they start production?

Comment: Boeing is currently investing a lot in the 777X which includes the technologies listed in that article, so you may consider that the Y3. Of course someday they will need an all-new aircraft for that market, but it will probably be a while before they replace the 777X.

Comment: Are you referring to the blended wing/body version?  The only other one I can think of is the SST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Y3 project is the third iteration within the Boeing Yellowstone project. Y1 was to be a replacement for the 737, but was put on hold after the decision to move forward with the 737-MAX. Y2 resulted in the 787. Y3 is supposed to address the 350-600+ passenger market, replacing the 777. To my knowledge, no prototype of such an aircraft has been built. Emirates was supposed to be in discussions with Boeing about this, but that was back in 2010, and since then I believe they have ordered the new 777-8X and -9X.